# multiple WCF services hosted in WAS IIS using netTcp protocols on same port issue

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, was

One of the services works fine but the other always throws a Socket Timeout 'forcibly closed' error.

I have portSharingEnabled='true' on both services and the netTcp Port Sharing windows service switched on.

I've done a lot of research on this but am unable to find the cause, any suggestions?

It's not an option to change the port either due to legacy system setup.

Each netTcp Binding looks liks this:

```
8033:*
```

Is that right or is the * the issue here? I've run out of ideas as you can tell.

Last point: It definitely isn't a timeout issue as I get the error on the client side instantly each time. All other binding config values are matched on both server/client side and set close to max as suggested by other similar issues here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell for sure. To diagnose the issue further, for the service and the client I would enable WCF Tracing and see if there is an underlying exception.  Here's a good blog article on how to create and read the log using the tools included with Visual Studio:

http://www.atulverma.com/2011/10/enable-wcf-tracinglogging-using.html

Comment: Hi Anderson, I've had the tracing switched on the server side for a while now but I see from your link that I might be able to see what's happening on the client also. I'll try it out first thing in work and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @BarryFanta right. Is the request getting to the server side, then?

Comment: No it wasn't reaching the server side. I researched further and got to the bottom of the issue with a colleague this morning.
It was down to the netTcp bindings after all.  
In each binding I updated them to:  
  
`8033:My.Domain.com`
`8033:My.OtherDomain.com`
  
Also update the endpoints with the hostnames above and after restarting the port sharing windows service everything worked.

This post solved it for me really: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b5b6169a-8af1-4017-9954-f9c843d4028a/]  
Thanks for your link to the diagnostic tool. I'm sure it will help in future.